# Anyone can tell me what lenguaje are use in this line of code?

Tags: vue.js

Im whatching a vue.js course and the presentator use this code for an if/else stament on the vue component.
Please if someone can tell me, to understand a way more better the code, im be appreciative.

```
<template>
    <!-- ? = if // : = else -->
    <div :class="[task.reminder ? 'reminder' : '', 'task']">
        <h3>{{ task.text }}
            <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
        </h3>
        <p>{{ task.day }}</p>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `<div :class="[task.reminder ? 'reminder' : '', 'task']">`

source: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Array-Syntax

this line will conditionally add array of class that will be joined by a space  . So on the first element of the array, it is a ternary operator which depend on `task.reminder` value, if it is `true` or something meet the requirement of the ternary, it will add `reminder` class or an empty string `''` which will not be added to the class, and on the index `1` of the array which is `task` will be added.

Say for example that your `task.reminder` is `true`, the div will be render as below:

`<div class="reminder task">`

if it is false, it will be render as

`<div class="task">`

> `{{ task.text }}`

source: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html?redirect=true#Text

this is how we render out a variable from vue into the DOM, wrap with `{{` and `}}`